# Can't import font awesome flutter?

Tags: flutter, font-awesome

Im new to Flutter, i use Visual Studio Code with Flutter extension. I try to import the package "font awesome" but i got an error. I search on internet but nothing solve that.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGJ7M.png)

[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iiy27.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots.  Take the text, and put it here, or pastebin, or DartPad, or a Github Gist, or ... (So many choices!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Flutter pub get
2. Import package
3. If still not importing then restart IDE
   hope this will work

Comment: `Flutter clean` is not necessary, i think they simply didn't `Flutter pub get`.

Answer (score -2):

If you run `flutter pub add font_awesome_flutter` or `flutter pub get font_awesome_flutter` and the import statement still shows an error, try running `flutter pub upgrade font_awesome_flutter`.